# Rewriting a plain javascript code into a code that uses jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plain javascript code that does not rely on external library. But given the popularity of jQuery and the fact that jQuery has become a de facto standard, I am wondering if it makes sense to rewrite the whole code for the sake of maintenance and extension in the future. Does it make sense to do so even if there is no particular problem with my plain javascript code at the moment?

Comment: @ubercooluk How does your comment help the OP?

Comment: Well, that depends on you. If you like to look into your app and say wow whatta clean and great code, then rewrite with JQuery, but If it doesn't matter for you, and if it's working that is enough for you, then you shouldn't waste time on something that you already have.

Comment: I think this is way too general and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the size of the codebase. If it's a very large job then 'if it ain't broke, don't fix it' applies. If it's quite small then it may help keep things more consistent.

There's no harm in itself however in mixing jquery and standard javascript, so anything new can be just written using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it only if i can take advantage of jQuery to make my code smaller and easier to maintain.

jQuery is simply functions written in vanilla JavaScript so we don't have to write them ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy answer for this one.

My thoughts: It depends. Jquery may help you develop new functionality more rapidly so maybe it would be good to use for future functions. If your application is big it may cause instability if you rewrite large parts of it at one time. Maybe you find some parts that would especially benefit from being written in jquery and refactor these pieces one by one over time? Since javascript is the foundation of Jquery javascript will be there even if Jquery goes out of fashion so it can't be that bad to keep.  Your main focus should be with the users; To keep them interested in you application and deliver new features that will keep them using your application. Very few users will care or even notice if you introduce a new library or not, but if your application breaks they will know. (It may however be very satisfying to introduce a library into your application that makes the code look good and easier to maintain).

Sidenote: These days I wonder if anyone knows what language / library they will be useing next year?